# How to draw several contours label in separate colors

Tags: plotting, labeling

Good morning. I have two equations (or more) that I want plot with ContourPlot colored with different colours and labelled according to equation order, in a automatic way. I have tried several solutions without success. My plot should remain as

```
g1 = x + 2 y; g2 = 2 x + y; b = {2, 2};
grosor = Thickness[0.01];
color3 = Blue;
color4 = Magenta;

coloresRest = {Blue, Magenta}; 
labelRest = Table[Text[Style["(" <> ToString@i <> ")", coloresRest[[i]]]], 
 {i, Length@coloresRest}];

ContourPlot[{g1 == b[[1]], g2 == b[[2]]}, {x, -2, 4}, {y, -2, 4}, 
  Frame -> False, Axes -> True, 
  ContourStyle -> Thread[{coloresRest, grosor}], 
  Epilog -> {Text[Style["(1)", color3], Offset[{20, 0}, {-2, 2}]], 
     Text[Style["(2)", color4], Offset[{-10, -10}, {-1, 4}]]}, 
  ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

I have tried with `Table`, `ContourLabel`, `Riffle` or `Epilog`, without success. For example:

```
ContourPlot[{g1 == b[[1]], g2 == b[[2]]}, {x, -2, 4}, {y, -2, 4}, 
  Frame -> False, Axes -> True, 
  ContourStyle -> Thread[{coloresRest, grosor}], 
  ContourLabels -> Table[Text[Style[labelRest[[i]], Offset[{10, 0}, {#1, #2} &]]], 
   {i, 1, Length@coloresRest}], 
  ImageSize -> 400]
```

or

```
ContourPlot[{g1 == b[[1]], g2 == b[[2]]}, {x, -2, 4}, {y, -2, 4}, 
  Frame -> False, Axes -> True, 
  ContourStyle -> Thread[{coloresRest, grosor}], 
  ContourLabels -> {Riffle[coloresRest, Inset[labelRest, Offset[{10, 0}, {#1, #2} &]]]}, 
  ImageSize -> 400]
```

I realize that expresión `{#1, #2}&` yield coordinates for labels, chosen by Mathematica. I'd prefer that and not to choose such coordinates.

Thank in advance

---

Sorry, but I forgot that

```
grosor=Thickness[0.01]
color3=Blue
color4=Magenta
```

and I prefer that Mathematida choose coordenates of label with  {#1, #2} & instruction.

Thank

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2362787).

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** As an alternative and more flexible approach, we can post-process `ContourPlot` output to inject contour labels.

```
ClearAll[addLabels]
addLabels[colors_, labels_: Automatic, threshold_: 1/3][g_Graphics] :=
  Module[{diag = ArcLength@Line[Transpose @ PlotRange @ g], 
   assoc = AssociationThread[colors, 
     labels /. Automatic -> 
       MapIndexed[Framed[Style["(" <> ToString@#2[[1]] <> ")", #, 12], 
        FrameStyle -> None, Background -> White, FrameMargins -> Small] &, colors]]}, 
  ReplaceAll[{d_Directive, l__Line} :> {d, l, 
     Module[{BSF = BSplineFunction[First@#], 
        pos = If[ArcLength[#] < diag threshold, {.5}, 
         If[Norm[Subtract @@ #[[1, {1, -1}]]] <= 
           diag threshold, {.3, .8}, {0, 1}]]}, 
       Text[assoc@FirstCase[d, _?ColorQ], #] & /@ (BSF /@ pos)] & /@ {l}}] @ Normal[g]]

addLabels[colors_, labels_: Automatic, threshold_: 1/3][Legended[g_, legend_]] := 
 Legended[addLabels[colors, labels, threshold] @ g, legend]
```

The first argument, `colors`, is a list of colors with the same length as `functionlist` in `ContourPlot[functionlist,...]`.

The (optional) second argument, `labels`, is a list of labels with the same length (if this argument is `Automatic` or not provided, the labels are taken to be numbers from 1 to length of `colors`).

The third argument, `threshold`, is also optional and it is used to control the number of labels and label positions on a contour curve. If a contour curve is *too short* (in comparison to the length of the diagonal of the plotting area) then a single label is placed in the middle of the curve. If the start and end points of the curve *not too close* two labels are placed at the two ends of the curve. If they are *too close* (as in a closed curve) two labels are placed so that they are not too close to each other.

We can use `addLabels` in two ways: (1) as the the setting for the option [`DisplayFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisplayFunction.html) by adding the option `DisplayFunction -> addLabels[colors, labels, threshold]` to `ContourPlot`, or (2) by wrapping `ContourPlot[...]` with it, i.e., using `addLabels[colors, labels, threshold] @ ContourPlot[...]`.

***Examples:***

```
{g1, g2, b} = {x + 2 y, 2 x + y, {2, 2}};

funcs = {g1 - b[[1]], g2 - b[[2]]};

colors = {Blue, Magenta};

options = {Frame -> False, Axes -> True, ContourShading -> None, 
   ImageSize -> 400, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]};

ContourPlot[funcs, {x, -2, 4}, {y, -2, 4}, 
 Evaluate @ options, 
 ContourStyle -> Thread[Directive[colors, Thick]], 
 DisplayFunction -> addLabels[colors]]
```

[image]

```
addLabels[colors] @ ContourPlot[funcs, {x, -2, 4}, {y, -2, 4}, 
     Evaluate @ options, ContourStyle -> Thread[Directive[colors, Thick]]]
```

> ```
>  same picture
> ```

With

```
funcs = {g1 - b[[1]], g2 - b[[2]], Cos[x - 1] + Cos[y - 1] - 1/3, 
   Sin[ x - 1] + x y Cos[y + 1] - 1/4};

colors = {Blue, Magenta, Red, Green};
```

we get

[image]

We can use the second argument of `addLabels` to inject pre-specified labels instead of automatically generated ones:

```
labels = MapIndexed[Framed[Style["(" <> ToString@#2[[1]] <> ")", #, Bold, 18], 
     FrameStyle -> None, Background -> White] &, colors];

ContourPlot[funcs, {x, -2, 4}, {y, -2, 4},
 Evaluate @ options,
 ContourStyle -> Thread[Directive[colors, Thick]], 
 DisplayFunction -> addLabels[colors, labels]]
```

[image]

Add the option `PlotLegends->"Expressions"` to get

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
{g1, g2, b} = {x + 2 y, 2 x + y, {2, 2}};

colors = {Blue, Magenta};

labels = MapIndexed[Framed[Style["(" <> ToString@#2[[1]] <> ")", #, 18], 
     FrameStyle -> None, Background -> White] &, colors];

Show[MapThread[
      ContourPlot[#, {x, -2, 4}, {y, -2, 4}, 
         Frame -> False, 
         Axes -> True,
         ContourShading -> None, 
         Contours -> {0}, 
         ContourStyle -> Directive[#2, Thick], 
         ContourLabels -> Function[{x, y, z}, Text[#3, {x, y}]], 
         ImageSize -> 400] &, 
      {{g1 - b[[1]], g2 - b[[2]]}, colors, labels}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This program and their users are incredible. I will have to study carefully the answer, I like.